# WPF designer issue referencing enum

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, enums

So I have referenced an enum in this example using the staticextension, which works fine at runtime, but fails at design time due to the error "Could not create an instance of type 'StaticExtension'."

I understand this to mean that it thinks it needs an instance of the enum type to actually reference it. However, the enum is defined in the window as static so I don't understand why it is having issues.

Is there any reasonable way to keep the designer working? The closest I have found so far is to put it in an objectdataprovider and create methods to return the enum values. Behind the scenes this is basically creating an object to reference the static type and seems like too much work to just pull the enum values out. The goal here is just to be able to reference individual enum types and display them.

```
<Window 
  x:Class="DaedalusGraphViewer.GraphViewerWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:DaedalusGraphViewer="clr-namespace:DaedalusGraphViewer">
 <StackPanel>
    <Label Content="testtesttest">
      <Label.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
          <MenuItem Header="{x:Static DaedalusGraphViewer:GraphViewerWindow+Test.test1}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
      </Label.ContextMenu>
    </Label>
  </StackPanel>  
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace DaedalusGraphViewer
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for GraphViewerWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class GraphViewerWindow : Window
  {
    public GraphViewerWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      Application.Current.MainWindow = this;
    }

    public enum Test
    {
      test1, test2
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known [bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/605614/xaml-designer-x-static-nexted-type-error-type-ns-class-nestedclass-was-not-found) in designer. The workaround is not to use nested types with designer.

Comment: I see. That's unfortunate. It means that I have to pollute the namespace with enums or create a specific enum namespace. Is that the common way of doing things?

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/361509/xaml-designer-cannot-handle-typename-with-nested-classes Fixed in VNext, so probably VS2k12.

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet: well, nested enums are *not* a common practice. Personally, I can't understand, why you've called this "pollute the namespace". Look at FCL, for example, and compare the number of nested enums with regular ones.

Comment: well i'm just a beginner, but that's how it appeared to me. So it's normal to have enums in the namespace as long as you have a good namespace structure so that the enum makes sense